# How to convert JSON to C# using Class hierarchy?

Tags: c#, json

I have following JSON and I want to deserialize using class. I have read few reference but it doesn't work in this case.

I want to create class which can deserialize following JSON and work fine.
Can anybody please suggest me?

JSON:

```
{
   "panels":{
      "LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1":{
         "lable_value":"New Panel 1",
         "rows":[
            [
               {
                  "name":"subject",
                  "label_value":"Subject",
                  "label":"subject",
                  "type":"String",
                  "required":"true",
                  "CanBeSecuredForCreate":"false",
                  "CanBeSecuredForRead":"false",
                  "CanBeSecuredForUpdate":"false"
               },
               {
                  "name":"scheduledstart",
                  "label_value":"Start Time",
                  "label":"scheduledstart",
                  "type":"DateTime",
                  "required":"true",
                  "CanBeSecuredForCreate":"false",
                  "CanBeSecuredForRead":"false",
                  "CanBeSecuredForUpdate":"false"
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

If there are 3 panels, above JSON has `LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1`, `LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL2`, `LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL3`. It makes really complications.

I am asking how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

So in your json, the "panels" object will have 0 to n "LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL{number}" properties, where n is unbounded.  This implies that the panels object is behaving like a hash table.

This should work.  IDictionary keys will get serialized into essentially dynamic properties in your JSON.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, panel> panels { get; set; }
}

public class panel
{
    public string label_value { get; set; }
    public row[] rows { get; set }
}

public class row
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string label_value { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string required { get; set; }
    public string CanBeSecuredForCreate { get; set; }
    public string CanBeSecuredForRead { get; set; }
    public string CanBeSecuredForUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

An example usage with JSON.NET

```
using LightInject;
using System;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new Rootobject();
            x.panels = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, panel>();
            x.panels.Add("LBL_EDITVIEW_PANEL1", new panel()
            {
                label_value = "",
                rows = new row[]
                {
                    new row
                    {
                        name = "subject",
                        label_value = "Subject",
                        label = "subject",
                        type = "String",
                        required = "true",
                        CanBeSecuredForCreate = "false",
                        CanBeSecuredForRead = "false",
                        CanBeSecuredForUpdate = "false",
                    },
                    new row
                    {
                        name = "scheduledstart",
                        label_value = "Start Time",
                        label = "scheduledstart",
                        type = "DateTime",
                        required = "true",
                        CanBeSecuredForCreate = "false",
                        CanBeSecuredForRead = "false",
                        CanBeSecuredForUpdate = "false",
                    },
                },
            });

            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in Visual Studio:

- *Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes*

Comment: That is not serialisation

Comment: "I want to create class which can deserialize following JSON and work fine"

Comment: @Haksu I am asking programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help. It seems that you ant to get a c# object from json string. I will show simpler example for deserializing json object in **Visual Studio**.
Right click on your project and search for **Manage Nu Get Packages**. When window opens search for **Newtonsoft** package. 
Now for your main program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public DeserializeObjectClass()
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Code for getting json object. 
        string jsonObject = "{'panels': {'address": 'random', 'id': '0'}}";
        panels myPanel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<panels>(jsonObject);

        Console.WriteLine(panel.adress);
    }
}

// And now for you panel object in c#
public class panels
{
     public panels()
     {
     }

     public string address { get; set; }

     public string id { get; set; }

}
```

I'm showing this just as **example** it may have some warnings or minor errors becouse I've not tested it yet.

Comment: yah but if he wants to learn how to deserialize json object it could be a starter